# C++ SNAP Library convert std::string to TStr

Tags: c++

In the ***SNAP Library*** there's a method that allows me to save a file in my pc here it is:

```
TSnap::SaveEdgeList(G, q, "Edge list format");`
```

in this function the 2nd argument its type is `TStr` which represents string types in ***SNAP library***

I have a string variable that contains a full directory of where I want to put my file like this:

```
string filedir = openFileDialog1->FileName;
```

What I want to do is to give the content of a string variable to a `TStr` variable like this:

```
TStr q = filedir;
```

But unfortunately it gives an error.
So i was wondering if anyone has an alternative solution or something Thank you

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick googling revealed that `TStr` can be constructed from a C-string via `TStr(const char* CStr)` constructor.

So, following will work:

```
TStr q = filedir.c_str();
```

Alternatively, you can pass `filedir.c_str()` directly as an argument.

Comment: thank you you're answer was very helpful BUT still it gives me now this errors: 1>c:\users\morganis\source\repos\project4\project4\myform.h(198): error C3867: 'System::String::ToString': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
1>c:\users\morganis\source\repos\project4\project4\myform.h(198): error C2530: 'filedir': references must be initialized
1>Done building project "Project4.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

Comment: @hamzasaber The error is in the code that you didn't show us. Ask another question as a separate post.